# Excel cumulative count array

Tags: arrays, excel, count

tried searching here but found nothing quite fit this query. I'd like to cumulatively count the 'TRUE's in an Excel array. The array is e.g. {TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE} which I'd like to manipulate to return {1;0;0;2;3;0;4}.

The array is produced by a number of clauses, which I'd rather not call repeatedly to get the answer else the formula will balloon in size !. The numeric result would then be compared with a value e.g. >=3 to return an array of TRUE/FALSEs which are then multiplied by 1 further array, before being converted to dates

All of this is using native Excel not VBA, which I'd like to maintain if possible. I've been trying options for days to get this to work, and would sorely appreciate any advice. Thanks very much for your time, ian taylor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the name *Arry* for e.g. `{TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE}`:

`Arry*MMULT(N(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,ROWS(Arry)))>=COLUMN(INDEX(1:1,1):INDEX(1:1,ROWS(Arry)))),N(Arry))`

This may well require committing with `CSE`, depending upon the construction within which it is employed.

Regards

Comment: Hi XOR, I had really hoped I wouldn't have to make calls from outside back into the array. May be I have to attack the overall problem (for which this is part of the solution) a different way. However I greatly appreciate your speedy reply, and will test this ASAP. Thanks again,   ian

Comment: What's the "call from outside" to which you are referring?

Comment: Just the fact that the array is called a further 3 times, and is itself the product of the manipulation of a bunch of other arrays, so I was hoping perhaps for some magical countif and row(indirect(rows))) structure, but I don't doubt that probably would be magic !  I have come up with a  solution where the array is called only once more and gets around the need for what I was querying originally, but that has given rise to another question which I may post on a new thread. Thanks again for your solution,